# fancybox image clicked image hide issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I'm using custom href with fancybox 3.5.x version, which not use wrapped a tag, when user click on image it opens on fancybox, but problem is when open it hide that cliked thumnail image, even fancybox closed the image has display: none css property, below is my code example.

```
<div class="galwrapsss"><img src="testssssk.jpg" /><img src="testsssskq.jpg" /></div>
```

JS Code

```
$(".galwrapsss img").each(function(){
       var originalImg = $(this);
       $(this).fancybox({
           href : jQuery(this).attr('src')
       });
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `data-src` attribute to set custom source?

Comment: You have to wrap an `a` tag around the `img` like so `<a href="testssssk.jpg" data-fancybox><img src="testssssk.jpg" /></a>`